# Inheritance in C++, how to initialize member variables in base class from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

i just opened up c++ today for the first time almost, and i tried doing some inheritance.

I have a class called Person and three classes that derive from Person called:
Retiree,
Adult,
Child.

The console asks for your age and in the case that you type 30 into the console i want to make a new adult object, and here i want to pass in the parameters: age, name and discount.

In java i would just call the constructor in the child class, as it has the super(a, b, c) in it. But when i try to do it here, it won't work, and i can't seem to figure out why.

Down below is two cpp files for Person and Adult showing their constructors and lastly the Main.cpp

I get this error when i try to create the object "Unhandled exception at 0x759EA842 in LearnCPP.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00AFF514."

Person.h

```
#pragma once
#include <String>
#include "BudgetAccount.h"
class Person
{

private:


public:
    Person(int32_t age, std::string name);

    int32_t getAge();

    void setAge(int32_t age);

    std::string getName();

    void setName(std::string name);

protected:
    int32_t age;
    std::string name;

};
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <String>

Person::Person(int32_t age, std::string name)
{
    this->age = age;
    this->name = name;
}



int32_t Person::getAge() 
{

    return age;
}

void Person::setAge(int32_t age)
{
    this->age = age;
}

std::string Person::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void Person::setName(std::string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}
```

Adult.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Person.h"
class Adult : public Person
{
private:
    double discount;

public:
    Adult(double discount);
};
```

Adult.cpp

```
#include "Adult.h"

Adult::Adult(double discount) : Person(age, name)
{
    this->discount = discount;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"
#include "Adult.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello Customer" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Down below you see a list of cities" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please enter your name" << std::endl;
    //Cin 
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;

    std::cout << "Please enter your age" << std::endl;
    
    std::int32_t age;
    std::cin >> age;

    //Check if the entered age is child, adult or retiree
    
    Adult user(50.0);
    
    std::cout << "Please select which city you want to travel to" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Adult` does not need to do anything with `age` and `name` in the constructor body, simply delegating to base class `Person` is sufficient. That is not the cause of your exception however, we'd need to see more of the code for that, the code you shared is fine.

Comment: The posted code can't possibly compile, so you must be running something else. Please post the real code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Looks like you're (mostly) doing the right stuff in what you've shown. Whatever's going BOOM! is elsewhere. The true beauty of the [mre] requested above is it's a powerful debugging technique. More often than not you don't finish making it because part way in the reduction in the noise surrounding the mistake makes the mistake obvious and you fix it. Winning!

Comment: You don't initialize in the constructor body in C++; that's what the initializer list is for: `Adult::Adult(int32_t age, const std::string& name, double discount) : Person(age, name), discount(discount) {}`.

Comment: Based on the way you're trying to construct `Adult user1`, the `Adult` constructor needs to be declared (and defined) with two additional parameters: `Adult(double discount, int32_t age, std::string name)`.  Note that it's slightly unconventional to put the new parameter first (`discount` in this case) for a constructor override.  It's more normal to put the base class stuff first, since it is generally more important.  You might also consider using setter methods to apply the "discount" after construction, to avoid a convention of bloated constructors.

Comment: Here is an example of defining the constructors outside the class: https://onlinegdb.com/rJiaxOm1_   And an example with defining the constructor inside the class: https://onlinegdb.com/B1rfbOQkO

Comment: I added all the code now. It gives an error at Adult::Adult(double discount) : Person(age, name).

Thanks for all the feedback i will try some of the stuff later

Comment: @Torben `Adult user(50.0);` You never pass `name` and `age` to the object you construct. See the previous comments about how to modify the `Adult` constructor to take all the expected arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
Adult::Adult(double discount) : Person(age, name)
{
    this->discount = discount;
}
```

You haven't passed in an age or name to this constructor, so it's using them from the parent class -- whose constructor hasn't been called yet.

Comment: So I need to pass in age and name after discount in the same parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, you haven't passed the value for name and age.

1. One solution to this is that you can change the constructor to take in the values for age and name.
2. Another solution is that you can define default constructor. You can also set default values in the parameterised constructor.

> ```
> Person::Person(int32_t age = 0, std::string name = ""){
>     this->age = age;
>     this->name = name; }
> ```